# How to add global style option for a react UI library?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, storybook

I need to add global styling option for my react component library. I have added global style as shown below

```js
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';

export const  GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`

  button{
    color: white;
    background-color: green;
  }
`;
```

and I have exported the component so that app consuming the my-ui-libray can use it

```js
export * from './GlobalStyle.js'
```

And I have used the global style as following in a react app

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import { GlobalStyle } from 'my-ui-libray';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <GlobalStyle/>
      <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

The issue is the CSS Styles are not applied to the button in the react app which is using my library. Is there any issue in my above code? Or is there a better way to achieve the same?

**Note:**

Global style work when the component in used in react Storybook as shown in following code, but once I build and use the library in the react app it does not work.

```js
const Template = (args) => <><GlobalStyle /><Button {...args} /></>;
```

**Reference:** (Add global styles section)

https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/design-systems-for-developers/react/en/build/

Comment: Try making GlobalStyle as default export

Comment: @Inder I tried this, unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: Global style work when the component in used in react Storybook, but once I build and use the library in the react app it does not work.

Comment: Edit the question with the code you've now. Have you changed GlobalStyle as default export?

Answer (score 1):

I find same issue on here [enter link description here](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/3008)

you can try put your global style outside of strict mode

```
<GlobalStyle />
<React.StrictMode>
    <App />
</React.StrictMode>
```

or

```
<React.StrictMode>
    <NewComponent>
        <GlobalStyle />
        <App />
    </NewComponent>
</React.StrictMode>
```

my globalstyle can working in second solution

Comment: I tested it with GlobalStyle wrapped directly inside StrictMode. It is working fine

Comment: @SinHong I tried this, unfortunately it is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

I also faces the same issue with styled components (version 5.3.5) when trying to create a UI library that exports a `GlobalStyle` component. The styles just won't applied when I imported it into the application. I am using rollup as the bundler. Not sure what causes the problem.

I switched to using emotion instead and the issue is resolved. Hope that helps.[Emotion global styles guide](https://emotion.sh/docs/globals)